# Find UID from EUID

Tags: aix

I am having a AIX 5.3 host to which we login and when needed uses pbrun tool to become root.Now the question is how do I find from command line as what user I have logged in to get this privileged/root user. If I am not wrong how do I find UID from my current EUID. Tried whoami and who am i both gives output as root.

Answer (score 0):

"who am i" is coming from utmp.  If utmp shows you as root then your pbrun tool must be changing it from what it was when you first logged in.

You could do:

```
ps l $$
```

which prints out a line with the PID and PPID.  Take the PPID and do that again:

```
ps l <PPID>
```

The UID column is your numeric user id.  If the PPID shows as 1, then pbrun did an exec rather than a folk / exec (which implies that it is a function or alias within your shell).  In that case, you could revert to "last" which will show who logged in to which tty at what time.

======

Another idea.  You can get the terminal the program is executing on via ps.  This is called the controlling terminal.  You can also get it via the "tty" command:

```
tty
/dev/pts/18
```

Now, feed that to "last" but remove the leading /dev/ part and take the first hit:

```
last pts/18 | head -1
myname    pts/18       myhost.mydomain.com       Nov 14 10:22   still logged in.
```

That is the last person to log into that particular terminal.  Will that work?

Comment: I do get PPID as 1. Problem is that in a busy system multiple users might login and become root which makes it hard to identify the correct tty.

Comment: I believe you have lost or overwritten what you need.

Comment: I mean the PPID becomes one and the corresponding UID is showing as 0 which is for root. I am not able to get the original userid who logged in

Comment: Right.  I believe you will not be able to.  utmp appears to have been over written and your original parent is gone.  Maybe, you could look at "last" and gleam it from that.  "last" will show you who logged into a particular terminal last.